# Is there faster method that creates vector with given mode and length filled only with NA values

Tags: r, vector

I need to create a vector with given mode and length. I use this code which works:

```
NA_vec<-function(vec_mode, vec_length)
{
  vec<-vector(mode=vec_mode, length=vec_length)
  vec<-replace(vec, vec==0, NA)
  return(vec)
}

a<-NA_vec("numeric", 20)
```

**Question:** Is there a faster way to do the same?

---

Edit1:

Another slow version but I think will work with any mode:

```
NA_vec5 = function(vec_mode, vec_length)
{
  vec<-vector(mode=vec_mode, length=vec_length)
  for (i in 1:length(vec))
  {
    vec[i]<-NA
  }
  return(vec)
}
```

Benchmark:

```
n = 1e5
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  DJJ=NA_vec4("numeric", n),
  Gregor = NA_vec3("numeric", n),
  G5W = NA_vec2("numeric", n),
  OP = NA_vec("numeric", n),
  OP_with_for = NA_vec5("numeric", n)

)
```

Benchmark output:

```
Unit: microseconds
        expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
         DJJ  269.213  348.7520  489.1965  382.3055  424.9365 10240.310   100 a   
      Gregor  351.713  430.0685  578.2138  475.4635  542.7665  8784.119   100 a   
         G5W 1051.979 1207.5065 1588.2552 1271.6510 1364.6125 24294.583   100  b  
          OP 1537.902 1776.1270 2732.4603 1934.4170 2101.9840 26363.014   100   c 
 OP_with_for 5772.263 6065.1595 6473.3508 6196.4100 6376.8055 11310.446   100    d
```

Comment: Due to `vec==0` your function doesn't work for, say, `"character"` mode.

Comment: In the title you only mention NA values, so just for NA, add an 'if statement', so, if the mode is NA, then do `rep(NA, vec_length)`, will speed up just the NA mode.

Comment: I am aware that you asked for (filling with) NA's but I often like to use things like: 
e.g. v <- numeric(10), respectively var <- "mode"(dimension); which usually is quite fast (as well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the appropriate `NA` type directly:

```
NA_vec3 = function(mode, length) {
  mode = match.arg(mode, choices = c("numeric", "integer", "complex", "logical", "character"))
  if (mode == "numeric") return(rep(NA_real_, length))
  if (mode == "integer") return(rep(NA_integer_, length))
  if (mode == "complex") return(rep(NA_complex_, length))
  if (mode == "character") return(rep(NA_character_, length))
  rep(NA, length)
}

n = 1e5
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Gregor = NA_vec3("numeric", n),
  G5W = NA_vec2("numeric", n),
  OP = NA_vec("numeric", n)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#    expr     min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  Gregor 210.160  224.4410  343.2125  244.5395  271.3385  7749.094   100
#     G5W 644.583  670.8525 1280.5191  683.7235  705.5860 11864.828   100
#      OP 995.436 1021.7055 2020.2795 1051.8545 1346.6415 12450.877   100
```

---

For historical interest, this answer was deleted:

```
NA_vec2<-function(vec_mode, vec_length) {
  vec<-vector(mode=vec_mode, length=vec_length)
  vec<-replace(vec, 1:vec_length, NA)
}
```

---

As another idea, I also tried this, but it was even slower than the original so I left it out.

```
# slowest yet
NA_vec4 = function(mode, length) {
  x = rep(NA, length)
  storage.mode(x) = mode
  x
}
```

Comment: A better solution

Comment: @Gregor Quick question, I am wondering why include the deleted answer, I see historical interest but in terms of answering the question? Just curious :)

Comment: @HectorHaffenden I think it is good decision for knowing that way too.

Comment: Mostly, in case someone else comes along and thinks "I know another way to do this, maybe it's faster!"---if they can see it tested here already I'll save them some time.

Answer (score 4):

A bit faster with `matrix` instead of `rep`

```
NA_vec3 = function(mode, length) {
  mode = match.arg(mode, choices = c("numeric", "integer", "complex", "logical", "character"))
  if (mode == "numeric") return(rep(NA_real_, length))
  if (mode == "integer") return(rep(NA_integer_, length))
  if (mode == "complex") return(rep(NA_complex_, length))
  if (mode == "character") return(rep(NA_character_, length))
  rep(NA, length)
}



NA_vec4 = function(mode, length) {
  mode = match.arg(mode, choices = c("numeric", "integer", "complex", "logical", "character"))

  if (mode == "numeric") return(matrix(NA_real_, nrow=length))
  if (mode == "integer") return(matrix(NA_integer_, nrow=length))
  if (mode == "complex") return(matrix(NA_complex_, nrowlength))
  if (mode == "character") return(matrix(NA_character_, nrow=length))
  matrix(NA, nrow=length)
  }

n = 1e5
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Gregor = NA_vec3("numeric", n),
  DJJ=NA_vec4("numeric", n)
  )


# Unit: microseconds
#    expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
#  Gregor 295.499 755.858 978.8608 768.0445 803.245 10907.67   100
#     DJJ 245.842 590.997 824.9774 603.2195 635.591 10660.85   100
```

Comment: Huh, never would have thought this would be faster. Neat!

Answer (score 2):

You can initiate your vector with a zero length and then attribute it the needed length, it will contain `NA`s of the appropriate type :

```
NA_vec <- function(vec_mode, vec_length) `length<-`(vec_mode(), vec_length)
```

Examples:

```
NA_vec (integer,5)
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
typeof(.Last.value)
# [1] "integer"
NA_vec(character,5)
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
typeof(.Last.value)
# [1] "character"
```

It's also faster that current fastest alternatives :

```
n = 1e5
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  mm = NA_vec(numeric, n),
  Gregor = NA_vec3("numeric", n),
  DJJ = NA_vec4("numeric", n)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#    expr   min     lq    mean median     uq     max neval cld
#      mm 204.4 241.55 268.680 263.25 285.00   472.0   100   a
#  Gregor 232.4 288.80 432.043 300.20 334.15 12499.1   100   a
#     DJJ 174.4 205.40 548.774 219.20 238.10 11456.3   100   a
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more time can be shaved off Gregor's answer, and the code simplified slightly, by using `switch` and avoiding the overheads of `return()` and `match.arg`:

```r
NA_switch <- function(mode, length) {
  switch(pmatch(mode, c("numeric", "integer", "complex", "logical", "character")),
         rep(NA_real_, length),
         rep(NA_integer_, length),
         rep(NA_complex_, length),
         rep(NA, length),
         rep(NA_character_, length))
}
```

This makes most difference when `n` is small:

```
NA_vec3 = function(mode, length) {
  mode = match.arg(mode, choices = c("numeric", "integer", "complex", "logical", "character"))
  if (mode == "numeric") return(rep(NA_real_, length))
  if (mode == "integer") return(rep(NA_integer_, length))
  if (mode == "complex") return(rep(NA_complex_, length))
  if (mode == "character") return(rep(NA_character_, length))
  rep(NA, length)
}

n <- 1e3
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Gregor = NA_vec3("numeric", n),
  switch = NA_switch("numeric", n),
  mm     = NA_vec(numeric, n)
)

# Unit: microseconds
#    expr min    lq    mean median     uq    max neval
#  Gregor 6.9 7.102 7.90506  7.301 7.7015 29.000   100
#  switch 3.3 3.501 3.91601  3.802 4.1005 10.601   100
#      mm 1.5 1.701 2.14605  1.901 2.0015 11.101   100
```

`rep()` and `matrix(nrow)` were equally fast here.  Not a patch on moodymudskipper's suggestion though.